# CSS let text go over image

Tags: html, css, positioning

You know how tekst (paragraphs) always wrap around a floated image, like so? [see img]

[image: example-float]

I would like the tekst to go OVER the image. Like in the example img below. I tried using `z-index` and `display:inline` but neither worked.

[image: example-what-i-want]

This is not my actual HTML, but basically what I looks like;

```
<img src="" alt="" style="float:right;" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed eros tellus, sit amet ultrices quam. Sed quis justo metus, quis gravida orci. Vivamus porttitor fringilla massa at luctus. Quisque lacinia diam eget justo tempor vehicula. Nulla fringilla libero sit amet tortor bibendum imperdiet. Pellentesque in risus vel libero pellentesque hendrerit. Suspendisse vehicula fermentum pretium. Sed elementum eleifend dolor nec aliquam. Nam ac viverra dolor. Vivamus vitae ultricies velit.</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing margin-top for the text <p> tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
 <img src="" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;" />
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed eros tellus, sit amet ultrices quam. Sed quis justo metus, quis gravida orci. Vivamus porttitor fringilla massa at luctus. Quisque lacinia diam eget justo tempor vehicula. Nulla fringilla libero sit amet tortor bibendum imperdiet. Pellentesque in risus vel libero pellentesque hendrerit. Suspendisse vehicula fermentum pretium. Sed elementum eleifend dolor nec aliquam. Nam ac viverra dolor. Vivamus vitae ultricies velit.</p>
</div>
```

The key is `absolute` positioning. Make sure the container has a position set (use `relative` if it doesn't have one currently).

(You may also need some `z-index`ing to make sure the layers are correct).

Answer (score 2):

You could either use `position: absolute` and `z-index` to move the image behind the text, or use the image as the paragraph's background image.

eg

HTML:

```
<p><img src="xyz.jpg" /> Lorem ipsum</p>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
p {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    background: url(xyz.jpg) top right no-repeat transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, here is what you want [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4D9q/1/) .

Z-index only works with `position: absolute`.
Countdown coordinates depends on the value of the property position.
If the parent element is set to `position: relative`, then absolute positioning of child elements determines their position on top of the parent.